# Django - how to initialize data in context processor

Tags: django

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    .....
    '../../.search_form'
)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    langcode = forms.CharField(max_length=10, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

**my_context_processors.py**:

```
def search_form(request):
    return {'search_form': SearchForm({'langcode': ...})}
```

How can I initialize the form in context processors with a langcode which is passed in every view of my app? I mean the context of all my views contains a `langcode`.

I have a language selection bar which is always visible for the users. Default is English. But my search is available in every language. So when a user selects for example Spanish and wants to make a search, the search will be made with the Spanish language.

I need something like `request.context['langcode']`, but obviously this doesn't work.
Thanks

**[EDIT]**

I already have another solution which is this:

```
class SearchFormMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(SearchFormMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context.update({"search_form": SearchForm({'langcode': self.langcode})})
            return context
```

And now I extend this class in each of my class based views. But I find this pretty annoying and was thinking about context processors.

Comment: Can't you simply get the `langcode` from a field of the search form?

Comment: @Germano I already have a language bar selection. something like `en | es | it | de `. It's useless and ugly to make again a language selection drop-down or so

Comment: How are you currently keeping track of the selected value?

Comment: I have a `class LanguageMixin(object)` which defines the `dispatch` method. Then, in this method, I have `langcode=kwargs.pop("langcode", DEFAULT_LANGCODE)`. And this view is extended by all the others.

Comment: So actually, the selected language is acquired in a special designated view. And is always passed in the context to whatever template

Comment: If the choice is persistent, you might want to use a cookie and then retrieve the value from the session: `request.session['langcode'] = ...`

Comment: yep, good point. Tomorrow I`ll work again on this feature. If it running well I'll tell you to post as an asnwer